# Line disappears after some seconds in windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, line

I'm trying to display some lines in a windows store app. I use the following XAML code for that:

```
<Line Stroke="White" Width="5" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="200" Y2="500" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

The rest of the page is like the "basic page"-template, I only added a button in the line just over it (or, better, I dragged a button control on the form in the designer view and pasted my line-code in the line after that.
The problem is not that the line doesnÄt appear, but that it disappears right after the starting animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to make your line 5 pixel wide, you should not use the `Width` property for that, because that makes your whole control 5 pixel wide (so nothing will be seen).

You have to use the `StrokeThickness` property instead.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I don't understand, why I can see it for some seconds before it dissappears. Does anybody know?

Comment: I have no idea. In fact I tried your code in a blank project, and on my computer I couldn't see the line at all.

Comment: It also was at the wrong place - somewhere at the right side. Perhaps it happens because my PC needs some time to set the size to 5. But I don't really belive it, because it isn't to slow (i5, 8GB RAM, SSD)